# ContextMenuStrip DefaultDropDownDirection not working

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created ContextMenuStrip for my NotifyIcon (in system tray). But, ContextMenuStrip's direction is always on the left. I've noticed that on many other applications (like skype), it is opening on the right side:

[image]

Mine ContextMenuStrip ist always opening on the left side. I've tried to set DefaultDropDownDirection, but in vain -> whatever ToolStripDownDirection I choose, it's always the same:

```
 _menuStrip.DefaultDropDownDirection = ToolStripDropDownDirection.BelowRight;
```

I would like to be able to change direction in which ContextMenuStrip is opening. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `Opening` event ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdown.opening%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) and `ContextMenuStrip.Show` method ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms160852%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

```
...
ContextMenuStrip _menuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip();        
_menuStrip.Opening +=_menuStrip_Opening;
...
```

Opening event handler:

```
void _menuStrip_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{   
    ContextMenuStrip menuStrip = (sender as ContextMenuStrip);
    menuStrip.Show(Cursor.Position, ToolStripDropDownDirection.AboveRight);
}
```